# Autogenerate Front End Form Field With jQuery

Tags: custom-taxonomy, jquery, taxonomy, autocomplete

I am attempting to autogenerate the terms in a custom taxonomy from a front end field. However, when I use the following code and try to type in a letter the dropdown menu that appears is a bunch of black boxes (screenshot below). Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more info. Thanks!

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'orderby'                => 'name',
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'             => false,
    'include'                => array(),
    'exclude'                => array(),
    'exclude_tree'           => array(),
    'number'                 => '',
    'offset'                 => '',
    'fields'                 => 'all',
    'name'                   => '',
    'slug'                   => '',
    'hierarchical'           => true,
    'search'                 => '',
    'name__like'             => '',
    'description__like'      => '',
    'pad_counts'             => false,
    'get'                    => '',
    'parent'                 => '0',
    'childless'              => false,
    'cache_domain'           => 'core',
    'update_term_meta_cache' => true,
    'meta_query'             => ''
);
$phpArray = get_terms( 'listing_taxonomy', $args );
?>
<script>
    $(function() {
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Calling console.log(availableTags) gives the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the autocomplete expects source to be `array, URL string and function return`. Even if you give `JSON` then it should have `label and value`. Which is not present here as you are simply output the `get_terms` with `all` fields.

So what I would suggest is just return the name of categories. Changing the fields from `all` to `names` will work well.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'orderby'                => 'name',
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'             => false,
    'include'                => array(),
    'exclude'                => array(),
    'exclude_tree'           => array(),
    'number'                 => '',
    'offset'                 => '',
    'fields'                 => 'names',
    'name'                   => '',
    'slug'                   => '',
    'hierarchical'           => true,
    'search'                 => '',
    'name__like'             => '',
    'description__like'      => '',
    'pad_counts'             => false,
    'get'                    => '',
    'parent'                 => '0',
    'childless'              => false,
    'cache_domain'           => 'core',
    'update_term_meta_cache' => true,
    'meta_query'             => ''
);
$phpArray = get_terms( 'listing_taxonomy', $args );
?>
<script>
    $(function() {
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
    });
</script>
```